# Recursion return values

Tags: java, recursion

I've been studying recursion in java for the past few weeks. I've stepped through this method as it runs (using eclipse) though i'm a little confused as to what is actually happening. What I see is the else statement making the variable "n" decrement until 1 and then finally access the if statement (as expected). This is where I get lost. At this point I see the "n" variable increment from 1 to 5 (5 was my input when the method was called), repeatedly accessing the else statements return.

Basically my question is why after returning 1 in the "if" statement does the code the jump to the else return ? Also, why after doing this does it execute 5 times instead of jumping out of the method ?

I understand this is a basic concept for recursion but it's completely lost on me apparently

```
public static long getFactorial(long n) {

    if (n == 1){
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return n * getFactorial(n-1);
    }
```

Comment: Each number `n` is pushed on the call stack (5,4,3,2,1) then returns start popping values off the stack... 2*1, 3*2*1, 4*3*2*1, 5*4*3*2*1

Comment: It's not really "jumping" to the else statement, it's returning to where it left off from the previous call. fact(3) becomes 3 * fact(2) becomes 3 * 2 * fact(1) becomes 3 * 2 * 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code jumps to "else return" from the previous execution. After 1 is returned for `n=1`, the function invocation with `n=2` immediately returns `2 * 1` - this is the reason of the sudden jump. You are confusing multiple separate method invocations.

```
invocation(2)
|
invokes ->      invocation(1)
|               |
|               returns 1
returns 2 * 1
```

After invocation with `n=2` returns a value, invocation with `n=3` immediately uses it to return its result - and so on. That's why there are multiple "else returns":

```
inv(5)
5 * inv(4)
5 * 4 * inv(3)
5 * 4 * 3 * inv(2)
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * inv(1)
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1    [return inv(1)]
5 * 4 * 3 * 2        [return inv(2)]
5 * 4 * 6            [return inv(3)]
5 * 24               [return inv(4)]
120                  [return inv(5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The initial call will be `getFactorial(3)` this will resolve to `3* getFactorial(3-1)` and continuing, so the general call stack would be.

```
3 * getFactorial(3-1)
3 * (2 * getFactorial(2-1))
3 * (2 * 1) // if statement is true and returning one and executing the recursion popping elements of the stack
3 * 2
6
```

Elements are kept on the stack, and are vulnerable to stackoverflow exceptions if the calculations gets long. Therefor it is a better practice in `Java` to make loops. This is what `Scala` does, when recursion is done tail recursively , then it will convert it to a loop at compile time. So there is often not a great reasoning for doing them, especially in an Object Oriented programming language, which is not optimized for recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Put Eclipse aside, and work through the code execution using pen and paper. Use a new sheet each time a method is called, placing it on top of the previous sheet. When you reach "return", discard the top sheet and put the value you returned into the calling statement. This is an accurate representation of the Java call stack.

So: start with a main call of `get factorial(2)`.

Write the whole of the method source code on a sheet of paper. Step through the code. n = 2. Is n == 1? No, so skip to the `else`.

Now you reach a call to `getFactorial(n-1)`. Since n is 2, that's `getFactorial(1)`. This is a new call, so mark where you're leaving the current execution, then put a new sheet of paper on top of the stack, and write the method source on it.

Step through the the code again, this time with n == 1. In the `if` statement, you reach `return 1`. So, discard the top sheet of paper. It has done its job, and returned 1. Resume stepping through what is now the top sheet. Remember that this sheet has its own `n`, which is 2. The current step is to return that `n` multiplied by the return value from the sheet you just discarded. So, return 2*1, discard the current sheet, and since you have no more sheets, you're back to the original caller and you have your answer.

Repeat this exercise with a larger first `n`, and it should become clear what's going on.

Back in Eclipse, the stack is viewable in the debugger. A stack keeps track of the chain of methods calling one another, even when recursion is not involved. It may be worth studying the stack of another paused program to understand this, before applying what you've learned to recursion.